# Import scss as text in Storybook

Tags: sass, storybook, custom-element

I'm setting up a webcomponents library (plain, not using lit or any other library) with typescript and scss, builds are done using esBuild.

I splitted up the webcomponents to use a separate html and scss file:

```
import css from "./Alert.scss";
import html from "./Alert.html";

const componentTemplate = document.createElement("template");
componentTemplate.innerHTML = `<style>${JSON.stringify(css)}</style>${html}`;
```

This works fine when building and using:

```
plugins: [sassPlugin({type: "css-text"})],
```

My scss is compiled and injected in the template as a text-string.

However ... I can't get this to work in my storybook. I'm using a standard config with the preset-scss addon and using webpack 5.

When looking at the output, undefined is injected as css.

Any thoughts on how to get this running in SB? Just want to import the scss as a css-string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this with Webpack and what the issue are, but you might look into `raw-loader` for WebPack or use the [asset/source](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) for WebPack 5.

Another solution could be to check out the [csshtml-module package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csshtml-module), that I created, which compiles into native JavaScript modules. You can probably set up your IDE to automatically compile these files into native JS/TS modules.

Because these becomes native modules, they should work in most library and frameworks. There are some guides on how to set it up in PHPStorm and VSCode.